# Float value converting before concatenate gets rounded in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my table, there is a `formula(varchar)` and a `value(Float)` column.

Example:

```
formula --> (A+B)/C
```

I am trying to create same expression with value

But my below example showing value gets rounded if it is big.

I am trying to do,

```
Declare @a float = 123456.235
SELECT CONVERT( varchar , @a)
```

The result is 123456.

Is there any way to keep same value as it is?

Answer (score 1):

[CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) function supports formatting as well. You can try with this

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @a, 128)
```

Comment: for this value @a float=1234556.235 result is 1.234556235E6

Comment: Declare @a float=29123455612589.23610

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), convert(decimal(25,5) , @a))

Result :29123455612589.23400 which is rounded again.